# Why is React showing "each child should have a unique "key" prop" error on console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, console

I'm trying to create a react app and on console showing this error, what does it mean?

*react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.*

I want solution of this react problem

Answer (score 0):

when you're using `.map()`, you should provide a **unique** key for each of the elements that you render.

```js
[1,2,3].map(item => <div key={item}>item</div>);
```